# How to know which programs have Numix icons?

Tags: icon-themes, numix

Specifically I'm interested in **PC games** that have **Numix Circle** ones.

Provided it was compiled by somebody, I'd like a list of completed icons. Tried to google it, but found nothing.

Comment: What do you mean? This is practically impossible to answer. There can thousands of PC games using those icons. What exactly you're looking for?

Comment: Well, if there are thousands of them, I'm looking for a list. If each icon sits in a seperate file, it could even be a list of those files (that get copied somewhere when you install **numix-icon-theme-circle** package), provided the files are named such that I could filter them for what I'm after.

Comment: That's out of the scope of AU and makes the question too broad

Comment: That may be, but before asking I checked and  90% of question about the Numix Icon Theme seems to have been asked here. Do you have any ideas which SE site would be a better place to ask this?

Comment: This falls under __Too broad__ category. Not duplicate. I don't know if any SE site allows this kind of broad questions.

Comment: I think it'a a very specific question. The answer being an extensive list doesn't make it broad at all. But I can tweak it a bit for your liking. Not a problem.

Comment: Think about it this way. You, as one person, were unable to find any list that satisfied your question. Now, you are asking someone else, as one person, to succeed where you failed. It's just too much content to fit (it might even go over the answer length limit, if there is one). What you can and should do is browse the theme itself and find the images, maybe compile your own list.

Comment: @o'rety The close reason explanation given was _There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs._ Now, you tell if this falls under this specification.

Comment: @Zacharee1: "Now, you are asking someone else, as one person, to succeed where you failed." This objection is applicable to every question on SE.

Comment: @Anwar: If you narrow a one-element set, you end up with an empty set.

Comment: @o'rety At least write good/clear questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing `numix-icon-theme-circle` package all the app icon files get copied to:

```
/usr/share/icons/Numix-Circle/48/apps/
```

(my folder lists 4276 files there). So now you can just filter for the names of the games or other programs you're looking for.

I was hoping for something more comprehensive (like an up-to-date list of what's completed put somewhere on the internet with info about the updates), but it's better than nothing.